# RxJava stream repeats twice for each record retrieved from database

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I have an RxJava stream that goes through all the records in a table, one at a time, sends an email for each recipient in each record and stores the status of whether the sending was successful or not. This loop repeats itself until all recipients have been read from the database and messages sent to them. The problem I am having is that code from the start of the stream (starting at getMessagesToSend) up to the storeMessageSent gets called twice for each recipient (except for the first recipient):

```
val msgToSendPublisher = BehaviorSubject.createDefault(0)

msgToSendPublisher.flatMap { startPos -> App.context.repository.getMessageToSend() }
    .flatMap { messageToSend ->
        App.context.repository.sendMessage(messageToSend)
            .doOnError {
                messageToSend.failureSending = true
            }.doOnNext { Observable.just(messageToSend) }
    }
    .zipWith( // 1 second delay between emissions.
        Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
        BiFunction { item: MessageToSend, _: Long -> item })
    .flatMap { messageToSend ->
        App.context.repository.storeMessageSent(messageToSend)
            .doOnError {
                messageToSend.failureSending = true
            }.doOnNext { Observable.just(messageToSend) }
    }
    .doOnNext { messageToSend ->
        msgToSendPublisher.onNext(0)
    }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(
        { messageToSend ->
        },
        { ex ->
            if (ex is EmptyResultSetException) {

            } else {
            }
        },
        {
            // Complete
        }
    )
    }
```

There is clearly something wrong with my stream. The stream should only advance to the next record when msgToSendPublisher.onNext(0) is called.

What is causing the stream to repeat twice for each record?

Comment: In the flatMap try removing doOnNext operator, because flatMap will return an Observable and in your doOnNext you are re-emmiting value again

Comment: That seems to make sense but when I remove it, the code will not compile. The flatMap needs an Observable returned. So how can I fix that if I remove the doOnNext?

Comment: Remove doOnNext and put a return@flatMap(Kotlin) before App.context..

Comment: What datastore are you using? Many Android datastores work like live notifications so if you update a record, active queries will have that record reemitted again.

Comment: @akarnokd I think you are correct. I am using Room and there are definitely updates, especially through foreign keys. If I comment out storeMessageSent, the start of the stream is no longer called. storeMessageSent is almost certainly causing the query for getMessageToSend to re-execute. Thank you for that deep insight. As much as I like Room, this is the part I don't like about it. When it automatically runs queries that interfere with other logic. Anyone looking at the code I posted would have no idea that some behind-the-scenes query is being automatically executed. That's kind of bad.

Comment: @UserOne Removing the doOnNext solved half the problem. The other half turned out to be an automatic behind-the-scenes query being run as pointed out by akamokd

Comment: If you comment storeMessageSent in the flatMap then the flatMap will return nothing, have you removed doOnNext and added return to both flatMap ? Good that it's solved but make sure that Room was the cause of the issue..

Comment: I commented out the flatMap and the doOnNext and the query for getMessageToSend will not get called. The only new problem I have now discovered after doing all that is that when the query runs until all the records are processed, I don't get an EmptyResultSetException as I would expect. I know that this is a different issue than what I posted, but if you have a clue why that exception is not getting generated, please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: I see you have doOnError operator where you set messageToSend.faillure, take a look at error handling operator(alternative to handle error), but post your new code &/or do a new post